# node.js Express 4 Session with custom sessionID error

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm trying to use a session ID from my mongo database as the sessionID within express-session and have these details stored within a connect-redis session store.

I keep getting 'TypeError: cookie required'

This appears to be a bug, but could somebody check my logic here please:

I've stripped the code down to it's bare bones and removed anything that's not required to create the issue.

```
'use strict';


var express       = require('express'),
    session       = require('express-session'),
    redisStore    = require('connect-redis')(session),
    bodyParser    = require('body-parser'),
    app           = express();


app.use(session({
  name: 'test',
  genid: function(req) {
    if (typeof req.sessionID != 'undefined') return req.sessionID;
  },
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    path: '/',
    maxAge: null
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: 'finbarboobar',
  store: new redisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    prefix: 'kTest:'
  })
}));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//router


app.route(['/'])
  .get(function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.email) return res.redirect('/admin');
    res.send('<h1>Login</h1><form action="/login" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" ><input placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" type="email" autofocus="autofocus"><input type="submit" value="sign in"></form>');

  });


app.route(['/login'])
  .post(function(req, res) {
    req.sessionID = 1;
    req.session.regenerate(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        req.session.email = req.body.email;
        res.redirect('/admin');
      }
    });
});


app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.email) {
    res.send('<h1>Hello ' + req.session.email + '</h1><a href="/logout">logout</a>');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});


app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.destroy(function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  })
});


app.listen(3001);
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was a bug within express-session package which has been addressed on [github](http://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/103)

The problem was that the `req.sessionID` needs to be be a `string`.  So in the case of the example above, I was sending a number and in my original code I was sending a `mongoDB._id` object.

The solution to the above would be to use:

```
req.sessionID = "1";
```

The solution to the real issue would have been to use:

```
req.sessionID = mongoDBSession._id.toString();
```

I hope this helps someone else with these issues at some point.